# NVIDIA graphics card unclaimed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

I was scrolling through my system specs for an unrelated reason. I produced the output via:

```bash
sudo lshw -html > specs.html
```

I noticed my graphics card was displayed in red as opposed to everything else in yellow. Specifically it says:

```
id: display
description:    VGA compatible controller
product:    GK107M [GeForce GT 650M Mac Edition]
vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
physical id:    0
bus info:   pci@0000:01:00.0
version:    a1
width:  64 bits
clock:  33MHz
capabilities:   pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list
configuration:  latency =   0
resources:  memory  :   c0000000-c0ffffff
            memory  :   90000000-9fffffff
            memory  :   a0000000-a1ffffff
            ioport  :   2000(size=128)
            memory  :   c1000000-c107ffff
```

Red apparently means my graphics card is `unclaimed` which I understand relates to an issue with drivers. When I use the Ubuntu "Additional Drivers" application, it states my computer is using the recommended drivers:

[image: nvidia drivers]

In addition, running `dpkg -l|grep -i nvidia` returns:

```bash
ii  libnvidia-cfg1-390:amd64                   390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA binary OpenGL/GLX configuration library
ii  libnvidia-common-390                       390.151-0ubuntu0.22.04.1                all          Shared files used by the NVIDIA libraries
ii  libnvidia-compute-390:amd64                390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA libcompute package
ii  libnvidia-decode-390:amd64                 390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA Video Decoding runtime libraries
ii  libnvidia-encode-390:amd64                 390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVENC Video Encoding runtime library
ii  libnvidia-fbc1-390:amd64                   390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Framebuffer Capture runtime library
ii  libnvidia-gl-390:amd64                     390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL/GLX/EGL/GLES GLVND libraries and Vulkan ICD
ii  libnvidia-ifr1-390:amd64                   390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA OpenGL-based Inband Frame Readback runtime library
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-5.15.0-25-generic 5.15.0-25.25                            amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-25
ii  linux-modules-nvidia-390-generic-hwe-22.04 5.15.0-25.25                            amd64        Extra drivers for nvidia-390 for the generic-hwe-22.04 flavour
ii  linux-objects-nvidia-390-5.15.0-25-generic 5.15.0-25.25                            amd64        Linux kernel nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-25 (objects)
ii  linux-signatures-nvidia-5.15.0-25-generic  5.15.0-25.25                            amd64        Linux kernel signatures for nvidia modules for version 5.15.0-25-generic
ii  nvidia-compute-utils-390                   390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA compute utilities
ii  nvidia-driver-390                          390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA driver metapackage
ii  nvidia-kernel-common-390                   390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        Shared files used with the kernel module
ii  nvidia-kernel-source-390                   390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA kernel source package
ii  nvidia-prime                               0.8.17.1                                all          Tools to enable NVIDIA's Prime
ii  nvidia-settings                            510.47.03-0ubuntu1                      amd64        Tool for configuring the NVIDIA graphics driver
ii  nvidia-utils-390                           390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA driver support binaries
ii  screen-resolution-extra                    0.18.2                                  all          Extension for the nvidia-settings control panel
ii  xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-390              390.147-0ubuntu1                        amd64        NVIDIA binary Xorg driver
```

Since I have installed Ubuntu, I have actually not been able to normally boot my computer. It normally gets stuck at the logo screen indefinitely. I've been booting my computer via recovery mode. This has led me to believe I've always had issues with my graphics drivers but to be honest I've had more pressing issues to dedicate my time to and have just been booting via recovery mode for the last month. But maybe it's time to address this issue...

Any idea how I can rectify this? Do I just have the wrong drivers installed?

Answer (score 0):

Unclaimed means that no driver was loaded for the NVIDIA card.

You can see this by the following line:

```
   configuration: latency=0
```

When the NVIDIA driver is loaded, this would look like this:

```
   configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
```

I would suggest to uninstall with purge the NVIDIA driver version 390
that you have installed from the repository, then install the latest
[DATA CENTER DRIVER FOR UBUNTU 20.04](https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/182614/en-us/).

For troubleshooting, see the article
 [BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)
.